# Void Overpayment through xero api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xero-api, xeroizer

I am trying to void overpayments through the xero api.

What I do is create an overpayment through the Bank Transactions end point with type RECIVE-OVERPAYMENT.

It creates the overpayment and then I save the OverpaymentID, but I can't seem to find any documentation on voiding the Overpayment again.

I have tried doing a post to the Overpayments end point with the OverpaymentID and the Status as VOIDED but I get a 500 error each time.

I have also tried to delete the bank transaction I used to create the overpayment but it just deletes the bank transaction and does nothing to the actual overpayment.

Does any one know what end point I should use?

I am not using a gem, I wrote the integration myself and everything is working except the voiding of overpayments.

Comment: If you get a 500 status there is either a bug on their side or your data is malformed, triggering an internal server error. I'd contact their support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete or void spend/receive-pre or over payments via the Xero API. However you can manually 'remove and redo" the bank transaction via the Xero UI.